# How can I float a row over an image using CSS in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5 and having difficulty overlaying text over an image. The HTML below is what I'm trying to achieve where there's a grid of images. For each image, (i.e. image1.png, image2.png), I want a row floated over the bottom of the image which includes a number and text title.

```
<div class="row">

<div class="small-6 columns">
    <img src="image1.png">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            No 1
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns">
            Image 1 Title
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="small-6 columns">
    <img src="image2.png">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            No 2
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns">
            Image 2 Title
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I can't figure out what CSS needs to be applied to that row to make it float over the image. Each time I've tried, the second row appears outside of the boundaries of the higher level row.

What CSS would achieve what I'm after?

Comment: JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/42XF7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the absolute position

```
.row > .columns{
 position:relative
}

.columns .columns{
 position:absolute;
 top:value;
 left:value;
}
```

You may also need to style differently the number and the text...
But more explaination, and an example of what you've done would be better.
jsfiddle is your friend :)

Comment: Thanks Audre - but I've still not managed to get this working. I've set up the following jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/42XF7/1/

Comment: ok, here's an exemple of what i explained : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audre7/8Syg6/1/) . You can see i put the container in relative position and the text in absolute so it can be over the image. Is that it ?